# How often do Savings Banks in India pay interest?

Tags: savings, india, bank-account

As per my understanding, Banks in India are to run under the directives of the Reserve Bank of India. How often do they pay dividends on the interest that they offer on Savings bank accounts? Every quarter, every 6 months or every year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banks in India are required to credit the interest every 6 months. However certain banks to certain customers even credit it once in 3 months.